# How to assign date to new variable?

Tags: javascript, date

I had take date into a variable like below.

```
var todayDate = new Date();
```

After this I am assigning `todayDate` to another variable:

```
 var yesterdayDate = todayDate;

 yesterdayDate.setDate(yesterdayDate.getDate() - 1);
```

After this I am assigning `todayDate` to another variable:

```
 var next30daysDate = todayDate;
 next30daysDate.setDate(next30daysDate.getDate() + 29);
```

How should I keep todayDate constant for above two variables. in my case it is chnging for very variable.

Comment: `= new Date(todayDate)`

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Sadly, that's not reliable in some JavaScript engines. (I know, right?) They'd want `= new Date(+todayDate)`.

Comment: when you run `var yesterdayDate = todayDate` you only copy the reference, not the value. You have this other SO question explaining it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Glad to say it looks like it's been fixed at the spec level, so the caveat above would only apply to obsolete JavaScript engines.